# Running QCacheGrind on MacOS with graphs

Tags: profiling, profiler, qcachegrind

I installed QCacheGrind [with homebrew](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/qcachegrind) successfully:

```
brew install qcachegrind
```

When I open QCacheGrind app on the tab "Call Graph" I am getting the error:

> No graph available because the layouting process failed. Try to run the following command did not work:
> `'dot -Tplain'`
> Please check that 'dot' is installed (package graphViz)

Graphviz is installed but doesn't work.

The workaround doesn't work anymore due to System Integration Protection.

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/dot /usr/bin/dot
```

So is there any workaround to get graphs visible in QCacheGrind?